# Connection rejected by remote interface (FB 2.1 SS linux x86)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm currently have a Firebird Super Server 2.1 x86 installed at my Ubuntu Server 11.0.

From time to time the server stops accept connections... resulting the error msg above (for clients)

**"Connection not established. Connection rejected by remote interface."**

To solve the problem, I need to restart the firebird service, and everything becomes OK!

The firebird.log does not tell me anything...

Any ideas about what is happening?

Comment: Sounds like the Firebird process is no longer running (or at least no longer accepting connections)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar instalation stack, and a similar problem.

I upgraded my firebird to version 2.1.4 after reading this [bug fix](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3285) that was backported from 2.5.

At the time, I also had to upgrade my hardware.  The problem has not repeated since, but I'm not 100% sure that the upgrade solved the problem

Hope this helps.

Alejandro